# Merge [bootstrap-4] and [twitter-bootstrap-4] tags

Tags: support, retag-request

Seems to make sense to merge these tags, since they refer to the same framework:

- [twitter-bootstrap-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap-4)
- [bootstrap-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bootstrap-4)